# evaluate the car of a list as a function in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am doing my homework and I need some help. I don't want you to do it for me just give me some guidance. What we need to do is write a function that takes a list of two numbers and an operator written in traditional notation (3 + 2) and yield the same function in prefix notation (+ 3 2) and evaluate it (5). I can easily convert one notation to the other but when I need to evaluate it what I was going to do was just force the car of the list (+) to be a function rather than just an element of the list and then pass the car of the list (3 2) as parameters to that function. The only thing is I don't know how to force the + to be a + instead of a '+'. Again I don't want you to just write the function for me just set me on the right track.

Comment: See APPLY and FUNCALL.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`fdefinition`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_fdefin.htm) to convert a [`symbol`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_symbol.htm) to a [`function`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_fn.htm) object (optionally) and then use [`apply`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_apply.htm) (if you do not know the number of arguments) or [`funcall`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_funcal.htm) (if you do) to invoke the function.

Comment: Or, alternatively, have a hash-table mapping from symbols to function objects. But as long as it would be (essentially) mapping + to #'+ and so on, your suggestion is probably clearer.